# Converting HTML form values of the same name to a Python list with Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, rest, flask

I have designed a basic REST API with flask and Python 3 to restart services on a locked down application. Using Postman, I would send a HTTP POST with an`application/json` body similar to;

```
{
    "fqdn" : ["my-fqdn-1.domain.com", "my-fqdn-2.domain.com"],
    "control_type" : "Start",
    "service" : ["Service 1", "Service 2"]
}
```

Sometimes, `fqdn` may be just 1 entry, other times, it could be 10. The same goes for `service`, sometime I might want to stop 1 service, other times stop 5. So far everything is working fine but now I would like to create a HTML form to provide similar functionality. On the form, I was thinking of having 1 row for `fqdn`, 1 row for `service` and then a dropdown for `control_type`. I could then dynamically add more rows for `fqdn` and `service` using Javascript similar to [this Stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091136/insert-a-new-row-of-input-tags-using-javascript)

What I am trying to figure out is how I would convert for example HTML inputs (not real HTML, just example)`<name=Service1>Service1</> <name=Service2>Service2</> <name=Service3>Service4</>` back to a Python List. For single values, it is easy;

```
fqdn = request.form["fqdn"]
service = request.form["service"]
```

but if I don't know how many rows to expect, I can't figure out how to process it.

Comment: Have you considered using a list and checkboxes?

Comment: The problem with using a list is that the only thing that is static is `control_type`. `fqdn` and `service` could be different for different users hence I was thinking the only way would be input.

Comment: if you are using wtforms that come with Flask, you should be able to make a macro that does this